# Asking about how can generate QR code in html in angular 4

Tags: angular

Here I am binding the QR code in html, but when I am trying to scan QR code on form but due to some styling problem it will not scan. And Qr Code came to service. I thought it could be some Boostrap issue. If you have any suggestion please share it.

My code:

```html
<img *ngIf="(result['qrcodefilepath'] !=null && result['qrcodefilepath'] !='')" 
     bind-src="result['qrcodefilepath']" 
     style="position:absolute;top: 7px;left:0.96in;"
/>
```

Comment: I don't see any such style issues in your code, the problem must be somewhere else. can you create stackblitz for the same?

Comment: Here is working example with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/qrcode?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Pardeep.when i scanning QR code is not scan.but if i download the QR code and scanning it will be work.

Comment: No Bro, please check my example this is working fine even when you scan. Have you checked?

Comment: yes your code its working here.But in my code QR code change automatically.Actually QR code  coming backend side

Comment: Yes, that is also not a problem at all, Problem seems somewhere else in your code